# My ggplot Index Chart doesnt look correct

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used investing to take YTD "IXIC" data then I did those steps

```
nasdaq.comp<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Burkay.Duran\\Desktop\\nasdaq.csv")
nasdaq.comp<-nasdaq.comp%>% 
  rename(
    Date = ï..Date )
nasdaq.comp[,1] <- anydate(nasdaq.comp[,1])
```

that was for clearing data and correcting time because time was like "5 apr 19"

```
ggplot(nasdaq.comp, aes(x =Date,  y = nasdaq.comp[,6])) +
  geom_line(color = "darkblue") + ggtitle("Nasdaq Component prices series") +
  xlab("Date") + ylab("Price") +theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1.8))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %y")
```

after that my graph looks like this

[image]

How can I correct the graph, it looks pretty weird that way.

Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: Your plot looks like plots wherein the y variable is a factor instead of a numeric. You can try converting that column (column 6) to a numeric variable.

Comment: Yeah i fixed it with changing it with a numeric one . Now I have this problem : how can I increase the spaces between numbers in Y axis. It is impossible to read those numbers

Comment: If the y variable is a numeric, there only should be 5-ish axis labels, which I expect to be spaced out enough to read the axis labels. Could you update your question with your current plot (and maybe the code to generate it) so that we could have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has millions and billions included in the column (ex. "1234.56 B") and so `read.csv()` brought it in as character. To solve this, I would strip out the characters with `stringr::str_remove_all()` in the `tidyverse`. You can also use `gsub()` or a variety of other functions.

The regular expression `"\\s\\w"` will remove a space followed by a letter.

```
nasdaq.comp[,6] <- 
  str_remove_all(nasdaq.comp[,6], "\\s\\w") %>%
  as.numeric()
```

Comment: ı used that code to fix it and it did work out pretty well actually ,
```plot5 <- ggplot(nasdaq.comp, aes(x=Date, y=Price, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Prices", 
       title = "Nasdaq Components Index Performance YTD")
plot5``` and looks like you are right, didn't realised that line had some Nas in it , after replacing them with 0 , my code also worked out too , thank you

Comment: That's great to hear. If this approach works, you can mark the solution as answered.